# plotly subplot applies different scales to each plot

Tags: r, plotly, subplot

I would like to create a back-to-back plot using `plotly::subplot` with the following code:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C"), a = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), b = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.6))

p1 <- plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~a, y = ~x) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickformat = ".0%", autorange = "reversed"))

p2 <- plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~b, y = ~x) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickformat = ".0%"))

subplot(p1, p2, shareY = TRUE, shareX = TRUE, nrows = 1, margin = 0)
```

My problem is that 10% on the x-axis scale to the left does not have the same width as it has to the right. How to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a reversed range list `range = list(0.6, 0)` in `p1` instead of `autorange`.

```r
library(plotly)

p1 <- plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~a, y = ~x) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickformat = ".0%", range = list(0.6, 0)))

p2 <- plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~b, y = ~x) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickformat = ".0%"))

subplot(p1, p2, shareY = TRUE, shareX = TRUE, nrows = 1, margin = 0)
```

[image: plotly_reverse]

---

To shrink the x-axis range on `p1`, use `scaleanchor`. In this case we can keep the `autorange = "reversed"` in `p1`. However, the `margin = 0` argument in `subplot` seems to be not working after setting this. Therefore we might need to manipulate `margin` to a negative value and set the tick intervals (`tickvals`) to avoid overlapping label on "0%".

```r
p1 <- plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~a, y = ~x) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickformat = ".0%", autorange = "reversed"))

p2 <- plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~b, y = ~x) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickformat = ".0%"))

subplot(p1, p2, shareY = TRUE, shareX = TRUE, nrows = 1, margin = -0.07) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(scaleanchor = "x2"), xaxis2 = list(tickvals = list(0.2, 0.4, 0.6)))
```

[image: tickvals]

Answer (score 2):

We can also achieve this by converting values in column `a` to negative and then reshape the data into longer format. Then a single plot with `barmode = "relative"` will give us the desired result. Change your padding, margin, and axes limits as desired.

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "C"), a = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), b = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.6)) %>% 
  mutate(a = -a) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-x) %>% 
plot_ly(x = ~value, y= ~x, type = 'bar', color= ~name) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'relative',
         xaxis = list(tickformat = ".0%"))
```

[image]